# Why API call no longer works since a refactor?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, use-effect

I made this useEffect code that works good in a screen:

```
 useEffect(() => {
    getDatasFromId(searchId)
        .then((data) => {
            const returnObject = {
                next: data.next,
                items: data.results.map(item => ({ name: item.name, url: item.url }))
            };
            setHasNext(returnObject.next);
            setDataToDisplay(returnObject.items);
        });
}, [searchId]);
```

But now, I made some modification and the API call is running without return (no error or whatever). My new code is this:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const apiUrl = getApiUrl(searchId);
    console.log("API URL : ", apiUrl);
    getDatas(apiUrl)
        .then((data) => {
            console.log("We get some data : ", data.results );
            const returnObject = buildDataObject(data);
            console.log("returnObject : ", returnObject);

            setDataToDisplay(returnObject.items);
            returnObject.next !== null && loadMoreApiDatasIf(returnObject.next);
        });
}, [searchId]);
```

I don't see the error in the new code.

Comment: In what specific way is this failing?  What's the problem that you observe?

Comment: Do you see the logs on the console? Did you try adding a `.catch()` block to output the error?

Comment: What about being SPECIFIC about this "error/problem" you are facing?

Comment: Sorry, the function getDatas is here : `

`export const getDatas = async (url) => {
    console.log("we gonna call the APi", url);
    return await fetch(url)
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .catch((err) => console.error(err));
};`

Comment: And I have no errors in the logs. Juste loading whitout end